# Proper handling of xcuserstate Files in Git

Tags: xcode, git

So I am using Xcode 5.0.1 and using the Source Control interface inside.

I made a project from scratch using Xcode and it does not seem to create a .gitignore.

In another project, every time I try to do a simple pull it says I have changes in the xcuserstate file and even if I commit them, there's just another change a minute later. I finally had to do discard all changes on one of the instances. (Going back and forth between laptop and desktop.)

Should these be ignored? Does anyone have a workflow they like? Seems like all the other nuisance aspects of Xcode projects have been greatly alleviated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the xcuserstate files to your ignore list in .git. Actually to avoid conflicts you should add these to your .gitignore file:

```
# Xcode
.DS_Store
#build file
build/
#personal settings
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
#xcode state
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
*.xcworkspace
!default.xcworkspace
xcuserdata
profile
*.moved-aside
DerivedData
.idea/
```

Comment: Yeah the reason I did another question is all the ones I found talking about ignore were before Xcode 5 and the project I made in XC5 did not make an ignore file.. ??

Comment: You can create this file if it is not created by default and add the above files in it.

Comment: Yeah I know. I was just thinking that if Xcode doesn't have an ignore, it must have some logic in it to avoid this, but apparently it doesn't. I have done a LOT of iOS programming, and had ignore files on those projects. For now added one and problem is solved.